# Multiple User Applications using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am building a user application in Python (for example), which makes use of MySQL. So I have created a database called `application_db` and for every new account I create a new `user`. When I build an entirely different user application, which will run on the same machine, I will create another database called `new_application_db` and also create new users. My concern is that the `table` `msyql.user` will contain users of both applications, which creates a bunch of problems. For example searching a user in a table with more data than needed (if I use application2 I do not need to know about users of application1) will affect performance. Furthermore, when a new user tries to use a username, he might not be able to, because this username is used by another user from another application.

I thought that creating a connection to a different port might solve the problem. Though when I try to do that in MySQL Workbench a get error.

Another thought was to create a new server on machine. Though in documentation of MySQL, the only thing I found refers to statement CREATE SERVER, which I do not think solves the problem.

Which would be the most appropriate way to address the problem?

Thank you in advance and I appologise, if the question is dumb. I am self taught and new in the world of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you misunderstand what `mysql.user` means. `mysql.user` is meant to store MySQL users, which are different from your application users. `mysql.user` stores users on your server who are allowed to log in directly into MySQL and not the users of the application.

A very common practice is to store a single `mysql.user` per application.

Now, you might ask: then how should I store the users of my applications?

The answer is simple: You will need a table for users in both your applications and this way the worry you have presented in your question automatically disappears.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now another question that comes to mind is how can I ensure that every user is the only one who has access to his own sensitive data, since I need to hardcode the password of user that administrates the database in my program? Also how can the application user be sure that he is the only one who knows his password, since administrator user has access to the table application.user?

Comment: @I.A.Gerogiannis Passwords are hashed in general in a one-way encryption. Your user types his/her password, but a one-way encryption obfuscates it. Let's suppose you have a hashPassword method. You call that at the time the user registers and store the result. Whenever the user logs in, you take the raw password, which the user is aware of and call hashPassword and compare the result to the text which was stored. This way only the user will be aware of his/her password, not even the sysadmin, accessing the database will be able to deduce the original value of password...

Comment: @I.A.Gerogiannis ...because the sysadmin will only see the hashed password of users in the database, but not the original value. So, if your password is 'foobar' and hashPassword('foobar') is 'sdjfsjdsfjdg', then you are the only one who knows that it's 'foobar', because the actual stored value is 'sdjfsjdsfjdg' and the sysadmin will only see that. As about hard-coding your database credentials on application level, I would not worry, because your server-side code can only be accessed by people who access your server and/or your source-code...

Comment: @I.A.Gerogiannis ...If somebody you do not trust has access to your server and sees the source-code, then your application is already hacked. So, don't worry of hard-coding the db password, but make sure that the password stays on the server and is not versioned by git, for example. Also, hash your password with one-way encryption and then you will not have to worry about impersonation of users.